# $\sum \frac{1}{\log(n)^{\log(\log(n))}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> I want to study the convergence of the series $\sum \frac{1}{\log(n)^{\log(\log(n))}}$.

My attempt is using the Cauchy Condensation, that is, studying the series $$\sum \frac{2^n}{\log(2^n)^{\log(\log(2^n))}}=\sum \frac{2^n}{(n \log (2))^{\log(n)+ \log(\log(2))}}$$ but it seems worse.

Maybe, I am forgetting some useful tool. $ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since for large enough $x$, we have $\sqrt x\ge \ln x$, we have $x\ge (\ln x)^2$.

Thus, for large enough $n$, letting $x=\ln n$, we have $\ln n\ge (\ln\ln n)^2$. Taking $\exp$ of both sides gives $n\ge (\ln n)^{\ln \ln n}$, or $1/n\le 1/(\ln n)^{\ln \ln n}$. Since $\sum 1/n$ diverges, $\sum1/(\ln n)^{\ln \ln n}$ must also diverge.

Answer (score 2):

The integral test works well here since the base used for the "substitution" in the Cauchy condensation test isn't so nice. Note that the below also works with the Cauchy condensation test, though a tad bit messier.

Assuming natural logarithms, consider using $x\mapsto e^x$ to get

$$\int\frac{e^x}{x^{\ln(x)}}~\mathrm dx$$

where the integrand is

$$\frac{e^x}{e^{\ln^2(x)}}=\exp(x-\ln^2(x))\gg1$$

so it clearly diverges.

Comment: You beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea by Cauchy condensation is fine indeed

$$\frac{2^n}{(n \log (2))^{\log(n)+ \log(\log(2))}}\ge \frac{2^n}{n^{\log n}}=\frac{2^n}{2^{\log n\log_2 n}}=2^{n-\log n\log_2 n} \to \infty$$